# Displaying just three consecutive values from database

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine a database table named **geography** that contains information for the world's countries, including each country's area in miles and kilometers. I want to write articles about each country, using my database to list certain statistics, including its size (area) - but with a twist.

An article about Vietnam, for example, would list the areas for Vietnam and for the next biggest and next smallest countries, ranked from biggest (top) to smallest, like this:

Malaysia | 329,750

Vietnam | 329,560

Norway | 324,220

I can easily create a table that displays a value for ALL countries. But can someone show me how to display just three consecutive values, with the featured country in the center?

A couple notes: First, the values in my database do not have commas (e.g. 18070). Also, some include decimals (e.g. 0.2). However, if this is a problem I could probably alter the data, adding commas and rounding the numbers off.

---

The answer below makes sense to me, but I don't understand exactly how to implement it; I'm getting a syntax error.

I'm using actual values, but I'm using a different table - gw_geog_states_geog - which contains values for U.S. states. I'm trying to access two values - IDArea (which lists ID's for states; for example, us-vt = Vermont) and Area (the size in square miles).

I suspect the problem is caused by this line:

```
$stm->execute(array(
 'MyURL'=>$MyURL
));
```

Here's the entire script:

```
$MyURL = 'us-vt';

$stm = $pdo->prepare("select t.*
from ((select IDArea, Area
   from gw_geog_states_geog
   where IDArea = 'us-vt'
  ) union all
  (select IDArea, Area
   from gw_geog_states_geog
   where Area > (select Area from gw_geog_states_geog where IDArea =   'us-vt')
   order by Area
   limit 1
  ) union all
  (select IDArea, Area
   from gw_geog_states_geog
   where Area < (select Area from gw_geog_states_geog where IDArea = 'us-vt')
   order by Area desc
   limit 1
  )
 ) t
order by size;")
```

My latest revision works if I add a parentheses at the beginning and delete the following:

```
$stm->execute(array(
'MyURL'=>$MyURL
));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `union all` and `limit`:

```
(select c.*
 from countries 
 where country = 'Vietnam'
) union all
(select c.*
 from countries
 where size > (select size from countries where country = 'Vietnam')
 order by size
 limit 1
) union all
(select c.*
 from countries
 where size < (select size from countries where country = 'Vietnam')
 order by size desc
 limit 1
)
order by size
```

This works fine so long as there are no ties -- and I don't think there are two countries with exactly the same area.

EDIT:

Try this:

```
$stm = $pdo->prepare"
select t.*
from ((select IDArea, Area
       from gw_geog_states_geog
       where IDArea = 'us-vt'
      ) union all
      (select IDArea, Area
       from gw_geog_states_geog
       where Area > (select Area from gw_geog_states_geog where IDArea = 'us-vt')
       order by Area
       limit 1
      ) union all
      (select IDArea, Area
       from gw_geog_states_geog
       where Area < (select Area from gw_geog_states_geog where IDArea = 'us-vt')
       order by Area desc
       limit 1
      )
     ) t
order by size;")
```

And then continue with the rest of the php code.

Comment: Thx - your script makes sense to me...except I'm having trouble incorporating it into my PDO query. I revised my original post, adding my new query. Can you see what I'm doing wrong? I think it's just a simple syntax problem.

Comment: Remove the parentheses around the entire query.  Or, add `select * from ( <my query here without the `order by`> ) t order by size`

Comment: I edited my original post, adding my revised query. However, I'm still doing something wrong. Maybe I'll figure it out if I keep playing with it.

Comment: Yikes, I'm still missing something. I used your latest tip, but had to add a parentheses at the very beginning - and it still doesn't work unless I delete the $stm->execute(array( PDO can be such a pain. ;) However, I marked your answer as correct. I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually.